# Calling Makefile of winexe from Makefile of Rsync

Tags: makefile, header-files, rsync, winexe

I want to merge two different source code and make single executable for that.
I have sourcecode1 as RSYNC and sourcecode2 as WINEXE. 
I want to integrate WINEXE code into RSYNC. For that purpose I place WINEXE code in RSYNC code.

I have called the WINEXE makefile located in WINEXE/source4/  in   Makefile of RSYNC as

```
WINEXE = winexe/source4

TARGET = $(WINEXE)

$(TARGET):

         @$(MAKE) -C $@;
```

and called the main function of WINEXE from RSYNC code.

But I got lots of the same error that Header file not found. But when I use "make" command inside WINEXE it works fine.

There are hundreds of header files, so it is not possible to change path of header files and libraries in each file.

please tell me how to integrate these two codes?

Comment: you have mentioned you are getting "same errors" ? Exactly which errors ? Where are you getting errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem resolved:
Tried to use follwing command

> .PHONY: winexe
>
> winexe:
>
> ```
>      cd winexe/source4 && ./configure && make 
>
>      @echo "i am here inside source"
> ```

In the outer Makefile, call the Makefile of inner folder.